# Javascript redirect no longer works after updating Chrome to 46

Tags: javascript, google-chrome

I was able to redirect to another page when using Chrome version 43 on Windows 7, but when I updated to Chrome 46 the redirect stopped working. Any ideas?

HTML:

```
<button onclick=" uploadForm()">Upload</button>`
```

Javascript:

```
function uploadForm() 
{
  var portalId = getQueryString("portalId", "none");
  var url= 'someWebPage?portalId=' + portalId;
  try {
    sforce.apex.execute("someController", "uploadForm", {portalId: portalId});
    window.location.href = url;
  }
  catch (err) {
    alert("Error: "+err.message);
  }        
}
```

Comment: So what is the error in the console? Does the alert fire?

Comment: There is no error. The only change was the update in Chrome version from 43 to 46.

Answer (score 0):

I strongly suspect that the logic in your code somewhere is busted.

I [replicated your code](https://output.jsbin.com/qecasa/latest) (minus the Query String Parsing) and it works perfectly.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <title>JS Bin</title>

  <script>
    function uploadForm() 
    {
      var url= 'https://paul.kinlan.me';
      try {

        window.location.href = url;
      }
      catch (err) {
        alert("Error: "+err.message);
      }        
    }
  </script>
</head>
<body>

  <button onclick="  uploadForm();">Click Me</button>

</body>
</html>
```